# Vimeo API call from browser

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I try to call vimeo API from browser's javascript. When I try to get access token (POST https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/access_token) I get 405 response and CORS error.
Is it possible to make API calls from browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating access tokens are not currently supported in the browser. Eventually they will be in a very specific circumstance.

For now you need to generate your access token serverside and share it with the client. Be careful though, these tokens do not have an expiration so your clients can take them and use them forever.

We will be fleshing out support for browser-based API calls in the future, but it's still a while out.

Comment: is this still the case? Thanks